# Letting every user mount a partition

Tags: mount

I can mount a partition with

`sudo mount -t ntfs -U "G9E575D9C8EA4" /media/pierrebenoir/wpartition`.

In my `/etc/fstab` I have

`UUID="G9E575D9C8EA4" /media/pierrebenoir/wpartition ntfs user,exec,noauto,rw,sync         0       0`.

I hoped that this would let me mount this partition when needed, without sudo. But no, when I click on the partition through Nautilus, I get the message that I'm not authorized to perform this operation. I thought the 'noauto' and the 'user' bits would imply that the partition does not get mounted by start-up, but can be mounted by a normal user.

Comment: When you click on a partition with Nautilus, it's gvfs / fuse that does the mounting I think - and that should be allowed by any (local) user by default. IIRC having an entry for the partition in `/etc/fstab` actually prevents this behavior - have you tried omitting the partition altogether (or commenting it out) in `/etc/fstab`?

Answer (score 1):

AutoFS is designed to solve this problem.  Take a look at it here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/autofs